How to find closest smaller number in array?
Consider this array:
std::vector<int> numbers = { 0, 4, 12, 60, 89 };

It is sorted and only has positive numbers.
What is the easiest way to find the closest smaller number in the array, preferably from <algorithm>? Example:



Number
Result




0
0


3
0


15
12


74
60


150
89




Since you describe a sorted array (which presumably in testing will be much larger) some kind of binary search is likely to be the "easiest" way to achieve this, where easiest is "lowest time complexity." Not sure anything in <algorithm> covers that.


What is the easiest way to find the closest smaller number in the array, preferably from <algorithm>?

One could make use of the already existing std::lower_bound (or std::ranges::lower_bound since C++20) for this. Check the example code given on the referenced pages.
For example, you could write a function as follows. I leave the error handling as well as corner cases perfections for you.
#include <algorithm>  // std::ranges::lower_bound

constexpr auto find_equal_or_closest(std::vector<int> const& numbers, const int query)
{
    // invalid query/ not able to find cases!
    // you could also restructure to return std::cend(numbers) from function.
    if (numbers.empty() 
        /* || !std::ranges::is_sorted(numbers) */ // optional check
        || query < *std::cbegin(numbers)
        )       
        return -1; 

    auto it = std::ranges::lower_bound(numbers, query);
    return (it != std::cend(numbers) && *it == query) ? *it : *std::prev(it);
}

See live demo

Lower bound returns the first one that is not less than the given value.

Adjusted based on your updated answer... I like the trick... still use lower_bound but then adjust the iterator afterwards....

retracting my close vote because this is much better than the other answer IMHO

@UpAndAdam As mentioned, it is not a perfect soln, rather a direction to OPs actual problem. OP has to think/ handle all the flows in the given according to his/ her corner cases.

Sorry forgot to delete my first response.. I have to say I love this, it's so simple and yet I never thought of this before. This to me is now a perfect solution.  And bonus points for the live demo with godbolt... I have to start doing that in my answers.  You are a truly great high rep user, I tip my cap to you.  I've had soo many unpleasant experiences with high rep folks lately that it is truly refreshing.  Exemplary back and forth as well. Thanks for showing me how to better answer questions myself.

when no smaller number is in the array you return an iterator to first element, I'd rather expect end in that case

oooh that is a good corner case. @463035818_is_not_an_ai hadn't thought about that.. fun corner cases.
